# GWT SuperDevMode in IntellijIDEA

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea

Does anyone know the steps needed to get GWT's SuperDevMode to run in IntellijIDEA? I've installed the prerelease Leda v122.639. I've selected "Use Super Dev Mode" in my Run config in IDEA. I never see the expected "The code server is ready" message.

Here's the output from IDEA:

```
workDir:/Users/xxx/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea12/gwt/xxx.6b734cae/xxx.e1dbb7c8/superDevMode/work
deleting: /Users/xxx/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea12/gwt/xxx.6b734cae/xxx.e1dbb7c8/superDevMode/work/com.xxx.xxx.xxx/compile-1
binding: user.agent=safari
binding: compiler.useSourceMaps=true
binding: locale=en
Compiling module com.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running the build from the command line its clear the IntellijIDEA compiler was stalling from lack of memory. I increased the memory given to java during compile in the build.xml and it started working.